# Symfony 2.3 nextBytes() not returning expected results

Tags: symfony, api-key

really new to Symfony 2 here. I am trying to implement the secureRandom class and nextType(int) to generate a 32 char random string. However, the method appears to be returning  non standard characters (UTF8).

**Code:**

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;

$generator = new SecureRandom();
$random = $generator->nextBytes(32);

...
```

**Result:**

```
#ïŽ+cÐÁ-ˆ5FZ{CD:­ïN2¨x…3ß,î2
```

Is there a way to specify I only want standard english chars?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Looking through the source code https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Util/SecureRandom.php  it seems that by default this function tries to use the openssl function [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) to generate the bytes. So to get the hex version of this you can call bin2hex.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Util\SecureRandom;

$generator = new SecureRandom();
$random = $generator->nextBytes(32);
$humanReadableString = bin2hex($random);
```

Or save a variable assignment and translate it in 1 step:

```
$random = bin2hex($generator->nextBytes(32));
```

Each Byte is made up of 8 bits. AKA 0 or 1(binary, base 2).

Every 4 bits can be represented by 1 hex value(base 16).

So if you ask for 1 Byte(8 chars) say "11101001"  then converting that to hex will give you "E9"(2 chars).

In order to use nextBytes to get a random 32 char string you will need 16 Bytes of data converted to hex values.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This converts the result of nextBytes(32) to regular text, but the length of the string is much longer than 32. I had to use substr() to shorten it. Is there a better all around solution to generating a random 32 char string?

    substr(bin2hex($generator->nextBytes(32)), 0, 32);

Comment: Thats because bin2hex is a hex representation of a the Bytes. If you want a 32 character string you can use nextBytes(16); 32 bytes displayed as a string would actually be 128 chars. Where as displayed as hex is 64.